# ES 6 - using get and set is understandable?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I learn ES 6 and I have question - using get and set is understandable?

For example:

```
class Country {
    get cities() {
        return this.citiesList;
    }
    set cities(value) {
        this.citiesList = value;
    }
}

let country = new Country();
country.cities = ['Tokyo', 'London'];
console.log(country.cities);
```

Why is it recommended to use set and get like this instead:

```
class Country {
    getCities() {
        return this.cities;
    }
    setCities(value) {
        this.cities = value;
    }
}

let country = new Country();
country.setCities(['Tokyo', 'London']);
console.log(country.getCities());
```

In second example I can:

1. this.cities instead of this.citiesList (get/set cities duplicates itself from this.cities)
2. When using a class, it looks better: country.getCities() than country.cities.

I have two question yet:

Which way is better:

A) Set cities by method (cities.setCities() or cities = [])

B) Set cities in constructor:

```
class Country {
    constructor (cities) 
    {
        this.cities = cities;
    }
}
```

Last question:

If I would like to have the number of cities listed and I use constructor then...

A)

```
class Country {
    constructor (cities) 
    {
        this.cities = cities;
        this.citiesLength = cities.length;
    }
    test () 
    {
        //operations...
        let op = this.citiesLength * 10;
    }
}
```

or

B)

```
class Country {
    constructor (cities) 
    {
        this.cities = cities;
    }
    citiesLength() 
    {
        return cities.length;
    }
    test () 
    {
        //operations...
        let op = this.citiesLength()  * 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post questions on more than 1 site at a time.

Comment: Hi from the above, I understand that your question is _Which way is better:_ this looks like an opinion based question and off topic in SO. please reword the question.

Comment: _"Why is it recommended"_ Recommended where? _"Which way is better"_ What is the definition of "better" as used at Question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will answer between lines.

```
class Country {
    get cities() {
        return this.citiesList;
    }
    set cities(value) {
        this.citiesList = value;
    }
}

let country = new Country();
country.cities = ['Tokyo', 'London'];
console.log(country.cities);
```

Why is it recommended to use set and get like this instead:

```
class Country {
    getCities() {
        return this.cities;
    }
    setCities(value) {
        this.cities = value;
    }
}

let country = new Country();
country.setCities(['Tokyo', 'London']);
console.log(country.getCities());
```

**R) This is syntactic sugar, both modifies the object variable (remember in JS classes are objects too). I prefer user getters and setters because is less code and more legible.**

In second example I can:

this.cities instead of this.citiesList (get/set cities duplicates itself from this.cities)
When using a class, it looks better: country.getCities() than country.cities.
I have two question yet:

Which way is better:

A) Set cities by method (cities.setCities() or cities = [])

B) Set cities in constructor:

```
class Country {
    constructor (cities) 
    {
        this.cities = cities;
    }
}
```

**R) It depends, use the constructor when you know that you always are going to set these properties and every object created from this class will have cities.**

Last question:

If I would like to have the number of cities listed and I use constructor then...

A)

```
class Country {
    constructor (cities) 
    {
        this.cities = cities;
        this.citiesLength = cities.length;
    }
    test () 
    {
        //operations...
        let op = this.citiesLength * 10;
    }
}
```

or

B)

```
class Country {
    constructor (cities) 
    {
        this.cities = cities;
    }
    citiesLength() 
    {
        return cities.length;
    }
    test () 
    {
        //operations...
        let op = this.citiesLength()  * 10;
    }
}
```

**R) B because in A you need to set citiesLenght every time you add or remove a city from array. **

Comment: *"remember in JS classes are objects too"* Remember, classes don't actually exist in JS, only objects and prototypes.

Comment: I know, that's why I say classes are only syntactic sugar, classes are objects.

Comment: The problem with choice A in the last answer is that it only stores the length once and won't change when the array's length changes.  You'd have to update the variable yourself any time you add or remove items from the array, or even when you reassign it to a different array.  With choice B, it essentially uses a getter for the `length` property, which will update as expected.

Comment: You are right. I missed that part where lenght is taken from a separated variable. Will modify my answer.